# Setting value to a particular cell using a dialog in table view of javafx

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am sucessfull in making a table column editable and updating value to it when the cell is double clicked. Now what I want to do is get the value from a txt field and set the value to a particular cell (column) of the selected row. I have gone through many research but could not find a proper answer. Javafx doesn't allow to directly edit values to a table except directly editing the cell and setting its value.

Thank you

This is a sample of so far what I have done.

Setting cellValueFactory to teh table columns

```
tblColQuantity.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue()
        .quantityProperty());
tblColQuantity.setCellFactory(col -> new IntegerEditingCell());

tblColRateWithoutvat.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData
        .getValue().rateWithoutvatProperty());
tblColRateWithoutvat.setCellFactory(col -> new IntegerEditingCell());

tblColTotalWithvat.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().totalWithvatProperty());
tblColTotalWithvat.setCellFactory(col -> new IntegerEditingCell());
```

The Inner class which helps me update the cell data

```
public class IntegerEditingCell extends TableCell<AddBillTable, Number> {

    private final TextField textField = new TextField();
    private final Pattern intPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d*\\.\\d+");

    // -?\\d+
    public IntegerEditingCell() {
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(
                (obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
                    if (!isNowFocused) {
                        processEdit();
                    }
                });
        textField.setOnAction(event -> processEdit());
    }

    private void processEdit() {
        String text = textField.getText();
        if (intPattern.matcher(text).matches()) {
            commitEdit(Float.parseFloat(text));
        } else {
            cancelEdit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Number value, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(value, empty);
        if (empty || value.equals(null)) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else if (isEditing()) {
            setText(null);
            textField.setText(value.toString());
            setGraphic(textField);
        }/*
         * else if (!empty){ textField.setText(value.toString()); }
         */else {
            // if((!value.toString().equals(null)) || (value==null)){
            setText(value.toString());
            setGraphic(null);
            System.out.println("Updated");
            System.out.println(this.textField.getText());


            // }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        Number value = getItem();
        if (value != null) {
            textField.setText(value.toString());
            setGraphic(textField);
            setText(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText(getItem().toString());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    // This seems necessary to persist the edit on loss of focus; not sure
    // why:
    @Override
    public void commitEdit(Number value) {
        super.commitEdit(value);
        // ((PurchaseDetail)this.getTableRow().getItem()).setQuantity(value.floatValue());
        System.out.println("Commit edit " + value);
        detectEditedCell(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not very easy to answer your question without knowing how you have set the table up (in particular, what class represents the data in each row, and what property maps to the column you are interested in). If you post the relevant code, you will get a better answer.

Comment: So which column are you wanting to update from a text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just get the selected item from the table, and call the appropriate set method corresponding to the property that the column represents.

For example, if you wanted a text field to update the `quantity` of the currently selected row, you would do:

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setOnAction(e -> {
    AddBillTable selectedItem = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if (selectedItem != null) {
        selectedItem.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
    }
});
```

As long as you are implementing your model class (`AddBillTable` in your example) with JavaFX observable properties (`StringProperty`, `IntegerProperty`, etc), then changing the property value will automatically update the table.

Comment: It works just fine. I created a [SSCCE](https://gist.github.com/james-d/f6ff00bfc691db99a3a1)